# Proving the limit and no limit of sequence ...

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to work with old material about sequence $\epsilon−N$ definition... wanted to check if I'm doing it correctly...

$$
\left|\frac{2n+1}{4n+5} -\frac{1}{2}\right|<\epsilon \\
\left|\frac{4n+2-4n-5}{2(4n+5)} \right|
    = \left|\frac{-3}{2(4n+5)} \right|
    = \frac{3}{2(4n+5)}
    < \frac{3}{8n}
    < \frac{3}{n}
    < \epsilon \\
n > \frac{3}{\epsilon} \\
N= \lfloor 3/\epsilon \rfloor +1$$
is it correct? second one:
$$
\left|\frac{5n^3+2n^2+1}{n^3+2} -5\right|<\epsilon \\
\left|\frac{5n^3+2n^2+1-5n^3-10}{n^3+2} \right|
    = \left|\frac{2n^2-9}{n^3+2} \right|
    = \frac{2n^2-9}{n^3+2}
    < \frac{2n^2}{n^3}
    < \frac{2}{n}
    < \epsilon \\
n > \frac{2}{\epsilon} \\
N= \lfloor 2/\epsilon \rfloor +1$$
how is this one? and last question(i need to prove that there is no limit 1 to next sequence so:
$$\lim_{x\to ∞} \frac{2n^2+3n+1}{n^2+2}\neq1 \\
\left|a_n -L\right|\ge\epsilon \\
\left|\frac{2n^2+3n+1}{n^2+2} -1\right|\ge\epsilon \\
$$
il choose $$\epsilon= \frac{1}{2}$$
so
$$\left|\frac{2n^2+3n+1}{n^2+2} -1\right|\ge\frac{1}{2} \\
\left|\frac{2n^2+3n+1}{n^2+2} -1\right|=\left|\frac{2n^2+3n+1-n^2-2}{n^2+2}\right|=
\left|\frac{n^2+3n-1}{n^2+2}\right| =\frac{n^2+3n-1}{n^2+2}
$$
now i need to make it bigger so:
$$\frac{n^2+3n-1}{n^2+2}>\frac{n^2+3n-n}{n^2+2n}=\frac{n^2+2n}{n^2+2n}=1\ge\frac{1}{2}$$
means that its true...
am i correct?....(not really sure about the last one..

Comment: yes it is correct.

Comment: @Surb what about the 2 i added? are they correct also?

Comment: 2) is correct. For the last one, it's confuse. What is $a_n$ ? and $L$ ? After, I don't see the correlation between the fact that $\frac{n^2+3n-1}{n^2+2}< 4$ and the fact that $\frac{n^2+3n-1}{n^2+2}\geq \frac{1}{2}$. Actually, $$\frac{n^2+3n-1}{n^2+2}=1+\frac{3n-3}{n^2+2}\geq 1$$ for all $n\geq 3$, what prove the claim.

Comment: I need to prove that $$\lim_{x\to ∞} \frac{2n^2+3n+1}{n^2+2}\neq1 
$$

Comment: I know, it's what I did since $$\forall n\geq 3, \left|\frac{2n^3+3n+1}{n^2+2}-1\right|\geq 1$$

Comment: well but in the common case(Which i cant solve so good as this...
i need to do something like this?
$$\frac{n^2+3n-1}{n^2+2}>\frac{n^2+3n-n}{n^2+2n}=\frac{n^2+2n}{n^2+2n}=1 \ge \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: It's fine :-) $\ \ \ $

Comment: so what i did now is correct and prove that its not L?

Comment: yes it's fine since you proved that $\forall N\in\mathbb N, \exists n_N: |x_{n_N}-\ell|>\varepsilon$ (and $n_N=N$ in your case). The thing I didn't understand in your first argument is the correlation between $\frac{n^2+3n-1}{n^2+2}\leq 4 $ and $\frac{n^2+3n-1}{n^2+2}\geq \frac{1}{2}.$ But it doesn't matter... what you did last is correct. But as you can see, you can also take $\varepsilon=1$.

Comment: well it was wrong( didnt done it for a long time... so i didnt remember quite well..), now after i fixed i guess its correct right?

Comment: yes, it's fine.